# For what n does $|A|=n, \ A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Could you help me check for what n does $|A|=n, \ A \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$?

I know that given two eigenvalues $\alpha, \beta$ of a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, $A^n = \alpha ^n (\frac{A-\beta I}{\alpha - \beta}) + \beta^n (\frac{A - \alpha I}{\beta - \alpha})$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$ and $A^n = \alpha ^{n-1} (nA - (n-1) \alpha I)$ if $\alpha = \beta$.
(Cayley - Hamilton's theorem)

I've determined the eigenvalues of this matrix, taking into account that its determinant is $1$, but I don't have any idea what to do next.

Maybe you could suggest another way of approaching this problem?

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Comment: I take it you're using $|A|$ for the order of $A$ as an element of the group. If $A^n=1$ then $\lambda^n=1$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$, so $\lambda$ is a root of unity; but it also satisfies a quadratic with integer coefficients (by Cayley-Hamilton). So, the question is, which roots of unity satisfy quadratics? That's a question about the irreducible factors of $x^n-1$. Do you know much about those?

Comment: Well, I know that there are at most n solutions to this equation. $x^n -1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + ... + x +1)$

Comment: We're working with integer entries of $A$, so only $1^n =1$  or $(-1)^n =1, \ 2|n$. Isn't that true?

Comment: You are looking for those $n$ for which the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi(n)$ has degree $1$ or $2$.

Comment: $\phi _n (x) = \frac{x^n-1}{LCM(x^d -1, d <n, d |n)}$. There are $\varphi(n)$ (Euler function) n-th pimitive roots of $1$, so the degree of cyclotomic polynomial, which has  exactly the primitive n-th roots of unity as roots, so the degree of this polynomial is $\varphi(n)$, and it is $2$ for $n = 3,4,6$ Is that correct?

Comment: Could you explain to me why the cyclotomic polynomial should have degree 1 or 2? I understand that we are looking for units of unity that satisfy the quadratic Cayley-Hamilton equation, but I can't connect it to the cyclotomic polynomial. And why do we admit degree 1? I think that the characteristic polynomial of this matric cannot have two equal eigenvalues, because it's determinant is 1, so $\Delta >0$?

Comment: @Don, I guess Derek Holt is pointing you also towards $A = \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi(n)$ is the minimal polynomial of a primitive $n$-th root of $1$ over the integers. Yes, your are right, it has degree $2$ for $n=3,4,6$, and the possible finite orders are $1,2,3,4,6$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you. I'm sorry, but could you explain to me more thoroughly why we consider cyclotomic polynomials of degree $1$ and $2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ is, by definition, the polynomial whose roots are the primitive $n$th roots of unity. If the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $A$ is $\Phi_n(x)$ (or a product of polynomials $\Phi_n(x)$ for one or more values of $n$), then we will have $A^n=1$ (or $A^m=1$, where $m$ is the least common multiple of the values of $n$). That's why we are interested in the cyclotomic polynomials. We are only interested in the ones of degree 1 and 2 because the characteristic polynomial of a $2\times2$ matrix has degree 2, so nothing bigger will show up.

As has been stated (but not, I think, proved, in the comments), the only qualifying polynomials are $\Phi_1(x)=x-1$, $\Phi_2(x)=x+1$, $\Phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1$, $\Phi_4(x)=x^2+1$, and $\Phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1$. So you job is to find, for each of these polynomials, a $2\times2$ integer matrix whose characteristic polynomial is that cyclotomic polynomial (or a power thereof).